# Billing and music store delivery problems in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

I've been having a number of problems with Ubuntu One and neither Canonical nor 7Digital have been able to help.

Firstly, months ago I placed an order and was charged double the actual price, $2 for each song.

Secondly, I ordered songs last night, about 12 hours ago, and they are still pending delivery despite the claim that purchased songs "Are magically delivered to your Ubuntu One cloud in an instant."

**Does anyone know who else I could get in touch with?** I want to support Ubuntu by purchasing my music from its store, but I can't continue to do so until this is resolved.

Comment: You need to contact U1 support via https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ to get support.

Comment: I did, and they never replied.

Comment: This question is EXPLICITLY permitted by the FAQ, but thanks for closing it anyway, I'm sure the community will be so much better off now.

Comment: According to a META user, there is an undocumented rule prohibiting support for paid services: 1) Thanks for letting me know in the comment above! Oh wait... there is none. 2) Thanks for the downvote, I deliberately broke that UNSPOKEN rule and really deserved that!

Comment: He is not a simple user and the rule [is not undocumented](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2819/25863). We are all wanting to help you out, but these cases unfortunately its out of our hands and control as you can understand.

Comment: @Razick No one downvoted this. The downvote was [done automatically by the system, when the question was closed as off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3894/22949). (If someone had, though, so what? The amount of reputation you lose is minuscule, and voting exists to let people express an opinion, not to serve as reward/punishment.)

Comment: @BrunoPereira Thanks for the link, but I don't think a post on Meta that has to be searched for (in other words I have to know it exists) is documentation.

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks for pointing that out. As for "so what" though, people seem to do it for very little reason, or in some cases not because of the quality but because of their personal preferences. It seems to me that the down-vote should be used when the question is low quality, not constructive and/or shows a lack of effort by the asker/answerer.

Comment: @Razick no worries man, it was more to document it (in case someone ends up on this post looking for answers like you) than another thing.

Comment: Anything we can do for you, let us know.

Answer (score 6):

Our server that handles these downloads crashed over the holidays, so it's currently working through the backlog of files to be downloaded. You should see the music show up in your account soon. I'm very sorry for the trouble.

Thanks,

Chase Livingston

Comment: Thank you for answering part of my question, is there anyway for me to get in touch with Canonical about the billing issues though? The contact link posted as a comment above was not answered when I used it months ago.

Comment: You use the contact support link I mentioned above. It will be answered. If it wasn't answered months ago for you, we're sorry about that. Perhaps an e-mail didn't make it through or something.